# How can I get block quotes inside org-mode footnotes?

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

Footnotes in org-mode are annoyingly different from the normal non-footnote environment. One difference is that one has to use "\par" instead of blank lines to separate paragraphs.  Annoying, but at least it works.  Another difference is that they don't seem to work with block quotes ("#+BEGIN_QUOTE" and "#+END_QUOTE").

Since I am mostly interested in exporting to Latex, I tried just using Latex's "\footnote" command instead of the org-mode "[fn:: ... ]" syntax.  But that did not help. I got a footnote that only contained the opening brace "{".

I also tried replacing the org-mode style block quotes with Latex's "\begin{quotation}" and "\end{quotation}", both with the org-mode footnote syntax and with the Latex footnote syntax, but neither of these attempts worked either.

Comment: Is this still a problem? I cannot reproduce it with modern org-mode.Org-mode version 8.3.4 (release_8.3.4-1026-gf0ff25 @ /home/nick/elisp/org-mode/lisp/)

Answer (score 0):

The following simple configuration should get you started, it uses the [csquotes](https://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER:\usepackage{csquotes}

(...)

#+BEGIN_QUOTE
"/Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum./"

-- John Doe [fn:: [cite:@doe2004title]. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nisi lacus sed viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada. Fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus. Sed tempus urna et pharetra pharetra. Sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra.]
#+END_QUOTE
```

It will export to something like this:

[image]