# Include quote inside org-mode footnote when exporting to latex

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode, footnotes

I've tried both `[fn:: ... ]` and `\beging{quotation} ... \end{quotation}`. Neither of them exports the quote block inside the footnote. I've also used `#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex ... #+END_EXPORT` and had the same results. There is also an old question about this topic but there is any answer.

My org-mode version is 9.3.8 and I use org-plus-contrib.
My emacs config is similar than scimax compiled with modules.

Here some usefull links

[Old unsolved similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889584/how-can-i-get-block-quotes-inside-org-mode-footnotes)

[My emacs config](https://github.com/gpetrini/scimax)

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a quotation environment within a footnote by using the `@@latex:...@@` construct, as in:

```
This *is* very interesting [fn:1:But not as interesting as it could be: @@latex:\begin{quotation}@@This would be a quote from somebody funny or smart.@@latex:\end{quotation}@@].  And we need to look at it.
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!